# Help identifying right angle (or 180°) USB connector part number

Tags: connector, identification

I am searching for the right angle (or is it 180°?) usb connector used in the product on the following webpage - https://thepihut.com/products/solderless-zero-dongle-for-raspberry-pi-zero?variant=31945282289726&currency=GBP&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=CjwKCAjwnK36BRBVEiwAsMT8WNUBdSzfdw_7kKOf7eKUF22Hht75-InsgJOA9PI0k-gfSMt71pO49RoC338QAvD_BwE

Assuming the relatively low price of the product I would assume it's relatively low priced and not some ultra specialised product. I have searched Farnell, Digi and Mouser with no success.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be a customer-specific product.

Comment: seems not so much  180 as extra-tall and installed backwards,